# React Native: error: bundling failed: index.js: "" is not a valid identifer name

Tags: react-native, npm, yarnpkg, package.json, metro-bundler

I have a React Native app which was running perfectly earlier this morning. I've deleted `package-lock.json` after mistakenly doing an `npm install` instead of a `yarn install`. Then I've ran `yarn install` and now when I try to run my app I get this error at the packager:

```
error: bundling failed: index.js: "" is not a valid identifer name
BUNDLE  [ios, dev] ./index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.
```

I've also closed packager and Vscode, removed `node_modules` and tried running `yarn install` again but I get the same error. I haven't changed a single line in my code and it was working before that.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

It is already opened as an issue.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27118

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27120#issuecomment-549832676

Simply you need to delete "node_modules" and again run the command:

`npm i` or `yarn`

Also, you can simply re-create the scratch project with

```
react-native init example
```

It will work as expected. They reverted the changes on @babel/run-time at 7.7.1 version.

Have fun

Comment: I've already tried it as I've said. I've worked around it by reverting to an old commit.

Comment: Can you check the @babel/run-time version?

Answer (score 0):

Delete node_modules and packages-lock.json, erase trash, close Metro Bundle, delete the app from emulator/simulator and run npm install, this way worked for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Reverting to an old version of my package.json worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and none of the solutions mentioned here or in the links worked for me. The issue was the `react-native` local and global versions were different.

`node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-ios` worked for me.

and while bundling, `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --entry-file...`

In short replace `react-native` with `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js` when trying to run or bundle